# Giving a specific rotation for each instance?

Tags: scripting, instances

I'm fairly new to blender. Basically, I want to create a bunch of arrows/cones that I can give the rotation of each arrow individually by loading some data. The problem is that I have 5000 data points, and I cannot create 5000 arrows, so I tried instancing; I know the that the idea of instancing is making copies of the same object, but I was wondering if there's a way that I can choose the rotation of each instance individually? So far, I have been able to subdivide a plane and create instances of arrows in each face; however, I cannot rotate these arrows other than randomly.  If there's even a way to do this manually I can figure out a way to script this and extend to 5000 points. I would appreciate it if anyone could nudge me in the right direction. Thank you very much!

Comment: For sure, Instance data are independent of Transform data, so you should be able to instance your arrows with rotations dependent on input data points. Could you give an idea of the format of your data-points? Maybe even the file?

Comment: I think geometry nodes can help you.
You can position each instance with a math function for example.

Comment: Hello Robin, thank you for taking the time. The data itself I can model the way I want. I can transform it into various formats. On my first try, I worked with a numpy file, either a matrix or a flat array. I don't know if my answer helps.. one approach that I tried was using geo nodes to instance cones in a plane; however, I don't know where or how I can give individual rotations for each cone :/. Thank you very much anyways!

Comment: Hi, Ismael, I reckon, if you provide an exemplary chunk of data-file, in a format that's practical for you, you may well get an answer that 1: Imports the attributes on to points (location & vector per-point). 2: Uses either more script, or a GN modifier, to instance arrows or anything else on the points, suitably rotated/scaled.